# My KeyListener can't read key inputs

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener, mouselistener

Right now, I have a class that extends `JPanel` and implements `KeyListener`. I've instantiated this class to another class that runs it in my loop. The KeyListener class looks like

```
public class Keyboard extends JPanel implements KeyListener{


public Keyboard()
{
         this.addKeyListener(this);
}

    public void update()
{

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{   

            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                 System.out.println("Made it");
            }
}


@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{
}
}
```

I implemented this in another class that utilizes a `MouseListener` just fine in the `Game` class. But for some reason, it won't listen to the keyboard.

```
public class Main

{

public static final int WIDTH = 640;
public static final int HEIGHT = 640;
public static final String NAME = "Game";

private static BufferedImage image;
private static Graphics2D g;
private static boolean forceQuit;

private static Game game;
    private static Keyboard keyboard;

    public Main(){

    }

private static void init()
{
    image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
    g.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    game = new Game();
            keyboard = new Keyboard();
}

private static void start()
{
    run();
}

public static void stop()
{
    forceQuit = true;
}

public static void run()
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    int frames = 0;

    double unprocessedSeconds = 0;
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double secondsPerTick = 1.0 / 60.0;
    int tickCount = 0;

    while (!forceQuit)
    {
                if(keyboard.isSwampland()){
                    game.setSwampland(true);
                }

        long now = System.nanoTime();
        long passedTime = now - lastTime;
        lastTime = now;
        if (passedTime < 0)
            passedTime = 0;
        if (passedTime > 100000000)
            passedTime = 100000000;

        unprocessedSeconds += passedTime / 1000000000.0;

        boolean ticked = false;
        while (unprocessedSeconds > secondsPerTick)
        {
            game.update();
                            keyboard.update();
            unprocessedSeconds -= secondsPerTick;
            ticked = true;

            tickCount++;
            if (tickCount % 60 == 0)
            {
                // System.out.println("FPS:" + frames);
                lastTime += 1000;
                frames = 0;
            }
        }

        if (ticked)
        {
            game.render(g);

            Graphics gg = game.getGraphics();
            gg.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            gg.dispose();

            frames++;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Main.init();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(NAME);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    frame.setContentPane(game);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Main.start();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so a number of issues...

## The Short Answer...

Use the [Key Bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), it overcomes the short comings of the `KeyListener` API

## The Long Answer...

`KeyListener` will only generate `KeyEvent`s if the component it is registered to is focusable AND has keyboard focus.

The problems I see with your code are ...

- `Keyboard` isn't actually added to anything, so it's not displayed on the screen, so it can never gain focus.
- The `KeyListener` really should be registered to the `Game` directly, it's just less components which need to be managed
- Using `getGraphics` from a `Component` is not recommended, this isn't how painting should be done.  Swing component's are double buffered by default, so it would generally be better to make use of it's inbuilt painting process and if you REALLY want control over the painting process, you should be using a `Canvas` and a `BufferStrategy`, otherwise run the risk of generating a race condition between your painting code and the APIs existing painting process

Answer (score 0):

I do this

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;


public class DrawPoints
{
    Frame f;
    KeyBoard key;
    Mouse mouse;
    Paint c;

    public void GUI()
    {
        f = new Frame("DrawPoints");
        f.setSize(300, 300);

        mouse = new Mouse();

        c = new Paint(mouse);
        c.setSize(300, 300);
        c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        c.addMouseListener(mouse);
        c.addMouseMotionListener(mouse);

        key = new KeyBoard();
        c.addKeyListener(key);

        f.add(c);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}

class KeyBoard implements KeyListener
{
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
        {
            System.out.println("SPACE");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Typed");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Released");
    }

}

class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DrawPoints app = new DrawPoints();
        app.GUI();
    }
}

class Paint extends Canvas
{
    Mouse mouse;

    public Paint(Mouse mouse)
    {
        this.mouse = mouse;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawRect(mouse.getX(), mouse.getY(), 30, 30);
        repaint();
    }
}

class Mouse implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{   
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int getX()
    {
        return this.x;
    }

    public int getY()
    {
        return this.y;
    }

    // MouseMotionListener
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        //System.out.println(e.getX() + " " + e.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("mouseDragged");
    }

    // MouseListener
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("MOUSE Entered");
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("MOUSE Pressed");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("MOUSE Released");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("MOUSE Clicked");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("MOUSE Exited");
    }

}
```